# Regular expression to get last colon in string and everything after it

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will get the last ':' and everything after it. This is my regular expression in C#:

```
Regex rx5 = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z.][^\s][^:]{1,}$",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

it works except it includes the ':' in there. How do I just get everything after the ':' not including the ':'?

Comment: `:([^:]*)$` would be a suitable pattern, but in the future, http://regexr.com is your friend.

Answer (score 11):

By not using a regex, but String.LastIndexOf and Substring()

Answer (score 2):

I would use this regular expression:

```
^(?:[^:]*:)+([^:]*)$
```

The first match group will then contain the rest after the last `:`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a group, and you could also rewrite the regex to something simpler:

```
Regex rx5 = new Regex(":([^:]*)$",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Then you have:

```
Match ma = rx5.Match("test:1:2:3");
if (ma.Success)
{
    // your content is in ma.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are better off doing str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(':')+1).

Regular expressions are powerful but don't try to use them when there is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use the following pattern:

```
Regex rx5 = new Regex("[^:]+)$",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: +1, but drop the useless Singleline modifier. In fact, it doesn't belong in any of the other replies either.

Comment: The expression: `"[^:]+)$"` is invalid syntax (un-matched parentheses). Additionally, (once fixed), this expression erroneously matches strings having no colon at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookbehind to not include the last ":"

```
 Regex rx5 = new Regex("(?<=:)([^:]*)$",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```